# Zombie processes, here we go again

Tags: python, linux, multithreading, multiprocessing, defunct

I'm struggling a lot with multiprocessing/threading/subprocessing. What I'm basically trying to do is to execute every single binary available on my computer, I wrote a python script to do so. But I keep having zombie processes ("defunct"), which end up in a deadlock if all 4 of my workers are in this state.
I tried lots of different things, but nothing seems to do it :(

Here's what the architecture looks like :

```
|   \_ python -m dataset --generate
|       \_ worker1
|       |   \_ [thread1] firejail bin1
|       \_ worker2
|       |   \_ [thread1] firejail bin1
|       |   \_ [thread2] firejail bin2
|       |   \_ [thread3] firejail bin3
|       \_ worker3
|       |   \_ [thread1] [firejail] <defunct>
|       \_ worker4
|       |   \_ [thread1] [firejail] <defunct>
```

There are 4 workers that I create as such :

```py
# spawn mode prevents deadlocks https://codewithoutrules.com/2018/09/04/python-multiprocessing/
with get_context("spawn").Pool() as pool:

    results = []

    for binary in binaries:
        result = pool.apply_async(legit.analyse, args=(binary,),
                                  callback=_binary_analysis_finished_callback,
                                  error_callback=error_callback)
        results.append(result)
```

(Note I use a "spawn" pool, but now I'm wondering if it's of any use...)

Each worker will create multiple threads like this :

```py
threads = []
executions = []

def thread_wrapper(*args):
    flows, output, returncode = _exec_using_firejail(*args)
    executions.append(Execution(*args, flows, is_malware=False))

for command_line in potentially_working_command_lines:
    thread = Thread(target=thread_wrapper, args=(command_line,))
    threads.append(thread)
    thread.start()

for thread in threads:
    thread.join()
```

And each thread will start a new process in the firejail sandbox :

```py
process = subprocess.Popen(FIREJAIL_COMMAND +
                           ["strace", "-o", output_filename, "-ff", "-xx", "-qq", "-s", "1000"] + command_line,
                           stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, preexec_fn=os.setsid)

try:
    out, errs = process.communicate(timeout=5, input=b"Y\nY\nY\nY\nY\nY\nY\nY\nY\nY\nY\nY\nY\nY\nY\nY\n")
    # print("stdout:", out)
    # print("stderr:", errs)

except subprocess.TimeoutExpired:
    # print(command_line, "timed out")
    os.killpg(os.getpgid(process.pid), signal.SIGKILL)
    out, errs = process.communicate()
```

I use `os.killpg()` and not `process.kill()` because for some reasons subprocesses of my Popen process are not killed...
This is possible thanks to `preexec_fn=os.setsid` which sets the gid of all descendants. But even with this method, some processes such as zsh will provoke a zombie process because it looks like zsh changes its gid and so my `os.killpg` doesn't work as expected...

I'm looking for a way to be a 100% percent sure all processes will be dead.

Comment: `.poll()` does not prevent zombie processes, it allows you to check if a process has finished.  If it returns `None`, it is still running.

Comment: Indeed it seems I haven't used poll() correctly, I have also encountered deadlocks with communicate() should I add `if not process.poll(): SIGKILL` ?

Comment: Please extract and provide a [mcve].

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt I have not been able to reproduce it in a minimal example, the bug occurs quite randomly, and probably because of the scale of what I'm doing (executing every single binary of my computer)...

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the `subprocess` module for this, you should use the `.kill` method of the `process` object directly instead of using the `os` module.   Using `communicate` is a blocking action; so Python will wait until for a response.  Using the `timeout` parameter helps, but will be slow for lots of processes.

```py
import subprocess

cmd_list = (
    FIREJAIL_COMMAND 
    + ["strace", "-o", output_filename, "-ff", "-xx", "-qq", "-s", "1000"] 
    + command_line
) 
proc = subprocess.Popen(
    cmd_list,
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE, 
    stderr=subprocess.PIPE, 
    preexec_fn=os.setsid
)

try:
    out, errs = proc.communicate(timeout=5, input=b"Y\n" * 16)
except subprocess.TimeoutExpired:
    proc.kill()
    out, errs = None, None

ret_code = process.wait()
```

If you want to run it in a non-blocking loop over a set of processes, that is when you use `poll`.  Here is an example.  This assumes you have a list of `filenames` and corresponding `command_lines` that you want to feed to the process creation.

```py
import subprocess
import time

def create_process(output_filename, command_line):
    cmd_list = (
        FIREJAIL_COMMAND 
        + ["strace", "-o", output_filename, "-ff", "-xx", "-qq", "-s", "1000"] 
        + command_line
    ) 
    proc = subprocess.Popen(
        cmd_list,
        stdout=subprocess.PIPE, 
        stderr=subprocess.PIPE, 
        preexec_fn=os.setsid
    )
    return {proc: (output_filename, command_line)}

processes = [create_process for f, c in zip(filenames, command_lines)]

TIMEOUT = 5
WAIT = 0.25  # how long to wait between checking the processes
finished = []
for _ in range(round(TIMEOUT / WAIT)):
    finished_new = []
    if not processes:
        break
    for proc in processes:
        if proc.poll():
            finished_new.append(proc)
    # cleanup
    for proc in finished_new:
        process.remove(proc)
    finished.extend(finished_new)
    time.sleep(WAIT)
```

Comment: Unfortunatly kill doesn't behave as I would, if the process spawns subprocesses, those will not be killed and will stay in the background... That's why I use `os.killpg()` and `preexec_fn=os.setsid` so that the whole group is killed

Comment: well, you can still use the code above with `os.killpg`. the concept is the same

Comment: I have updated my question to explain better what I'm looking for