# Python script finishes but process still alive

Tags: python, linux, tensorflow, process, strace

I don't know if this question will be too broad but I'll give it a try.

I'm running a fairly large python-project which got loads of dependencies, dynamic imports e.t.c. so it's hard to track down the root cause for my issue. The project is a deeplearning project which uses Tensorflow (1.14 at the moment). The problem is that after everything has been run, roughly 1 out of 5 runs gets stuck. For the stuck jobs I can still see the process if i run `ps aux` (in an interuptable sleep-state) and if i use `strace` I can not see any exit-codes beeing sent. The wrapping script (which is part of a CI-chain, still think that python is running and never finishes.

Adding `exit(0)` does not help (but nothing after that line will get executed). I've tried looking through everything related to multiprocessing and file-handling but that does not seem to be the issue with the code. Right now im suspecting something in Tensorflow. Python is executed within a cgroup and I can not find any other processes there.

So, I've got two questions:

1. Can I somehow detect why python does not finish?
2. Can I force python to exit? I know I can get the pid and then simply kill the process from within python-itself, but that means a non-zero exit-code which does not work well with the CI-system which interprets it as failed.

Comment: I had a similar issue a while ago, I suggest you take a look at [the post I did back then](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59769560/zombie-processes-here-we-go-again), maybe it will somehow help you...

Comment: Can you run GDB to attach to the process (`gdb /path/to/python-interpreter -p pid`) and get a stack trace with `thread apply all bt` ? Even better would be if you can reproduce this using the debugging version of python (see if you can install a package named `python-dbg`), because then you''ll have access to the python-specific GDB command `py-bt`.

Comment: I have been able to attach to the process using gdb, but I'm not sure on how to interpret the result. All i get is a lot of `New Thread` and `Thread ... Exited`. For jobs that does not get stuck, I get back the `gdb`-promt and it tells me the process exited normally. For jobs that does not get stuck, I do not get the promt back. If i open a new `gdb`-session, `thread apply all bt` gives an empty result.